# How can I get all the links from telegram message using C#?

Tags: c#, function, bots, telegram

I need to parse the message from the bot which sends some introductory links. However, it returns them as a formatted message, and as a result I can't parse it using message.Text method.

I use Telegram.Bot NuGet package for C#.

Is there any way to get a message without formatting so that I will be enabled to see all the links straight?

```
public static async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (update.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.Message)
    {
        var message = update.Message;                
        Console.Writeline(//here I need to return a list of links for example)
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation has information about how to find this information. 

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity

Comment: DONE!  
var ent = message.Entities;
                foreach (MessageEntity e in ent)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Url);
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
var messageEntities = message.Entities!;
var links = messageEntities.All(x => x.Type == MessageEntityType.TextLink | x.Type == MessageEntityType.Url);
```

All messageEntities have their own type and by using LINQ you could easily get them

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**